# Load and use type from the string class name

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

I have this method signature

```
Public Function As CreateWorkItem(Of T)() As WorkItem
```

What is the correct way to invoke this method having string representation of T"?

My failed attempt (simplified for clarity):

```
Dim controllerType As Type = Type.GetType("AccountingController")
CreateWorkItem(Of controllerType)()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use reflection to call generic Method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use a shared factory method instead of generics:

```
  Public Class WorkItem
    Property MyProperty As String
    Public Shared Function CreateWorkItem(TypeName As String) As WorkItem
      Static sstrNamespace As String = ""
      If sstrNamespace = "" Then
        sstrNamespace = GetType(WorkItem).FullName
        sstrNamespace = sstrNamespace.Substring(0, sstrNamespace.Length - 8) '"WorkItem"=8 characters
      End If
      Dim strFullName As String = sstrNamespace & TypeName 'assume qualified namespace of subclasses are the same as the WorkItem base class
      Dim wi As WorkItem = Nothing
      Try
        wi = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(strFullName)
      Catch ex As Exception
      End Try
      Return wi
    End Function
  End Class

  Public Class AccountingController
    Inherits WorkItem
    Sub New()
      Me.MyProperty = "AccountingController"
    End Sub
  End Class

  Public Class SomethingElse
    Inherits WorkItem
    Sub New()
      Me.MyProperty = "SomethingElse"
    End Sub
  End Class

  Sub Main()
    Dim wi As WorkItem = WorkItem.CreateWorkItem("AccountingController")
    MsgBox(wi.MyProperty)
    Dim wi2 As WorkItem = WorkItem.CreateWorkItem("SomethingElse")
    MsgBox(wi2.MyProperty)
  End Sub
```

Comment: The select case part will defeat the purpose of generic in this case because i want to use the class  without needing to know what type of controller is coming in. The string name of the class comes from database.

Comment: OK, I have reworked it to use reflection to create the class, to avoid the SELECT CASE. I still think a factory method is a better solution than using generics